# Browsers recomendations that work without "modern" glibc and libstdc++

Tags: gcc, browser, glibc

Recently a website that I use was modified, and with that, I can no longer bid on an auction I participate in.

I use an Firefox 30, a Firefox 45 and a Palemoon 27.9.4, but neither works anymore.

To get a newer version of any of these is not realistic, a couple of them  probably are beyond my reach, which are GLibc, libstdc++ and similar libs, since they would require me to compile a newer gcc, and I just do not have the disk space required to do that.

Finding binary packages of these libraries or of modern browsers does not seem to be realistic, since I am on a Ubuntu 10.04.

So my best hypothesis it to find a contemporary browser that can work on the required website is to find a browser that is written in C, since it could be compiled by my gcc.

So anything that isn't Chromium or Firefox would be a worth candidate.

P.s: Lynx unfortunately does not seem to work, since I need to do login in the website and it did not work.

Comment: Doesn't Ubuntu 10.04 provide some browser packages? Do you want to a modern web browser without modern dependency which seems to be impossible? Or you just want to use a specific website on Ubuntu 10.04 without too much compiling which need you tell people what web site exactly? Not all web site use the same technology, some of them might need modern OS feature which might be not possible on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upgrade to a newer release of Ubuntu? 10.04 hasn’t been supported for nearly four years!

Comment: @– 炸鱼薯条德里克 Yes it does provide, but what would be the point if they would not work?  And I do not want a modern web browser without modern dependency, I want one that does not require modern libc and associate libraries.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt, it is not possible.

Comment: If you’re considering building stuff from source, have you considered building the current ESR of Firefox from source?

Comment: @Stephen Kitt. I do not know by sure what ESR means (extended support release perhaps?). I do know that Firefox requires a more recent gcc and associated libraries than the one I have here.

Comment: Ah yes, you need GCC 4.9, which is newer than your release of Ubuntu. You’d also need Rust, and probably a newer version of Python than the version you have...